# How to return only object that exist in a function

Tags: r, function, return, missing-data

I´m trying to write a function in which I´m creating vectors such as a, b, c. I wrote several conditional statements to create these vectors and some of them might not exist at the end of the function. I´m struggling to write the return of the function; I would like to return them as lists:

```
return(list(a, b, c))
```

but I need to find a way to re-write it in a way that for example, if b doesn't exist, a and c will be returned and perhaps I can add a message of "doesn't exist" for b.

Can you please help me in finding an easy solution? Thanks!

Comment: What defines that b doesn't exist? Like is it an NA value?

Comment: No it´s just an unexistent object. I wrote the function to create b if one of the inputs has a certain dimension.

Comment: @AnaAntunes I've slightly edited the answer. If you like, feel free to elaborate your question, I'll see if I can improve the answer later tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant, but this could do it.

If you need to check for the existence of a lot of objects, then it is better to write what I wrote in the if else in a functional form.

```
func <- function() {

 a <- 1 # so a exists

 ret_list <- list()
 if (exists("a", inherits = FALSE)) {
   ret_list <- c(ret_list, a = a)
 } else {
   ret_list <- c(ret_list, a = "a doesn't exist")
 }


 if (exists("b", inherits = FALSE)) {
  ret_list <- c(ret_list, b = b)
 } else {
  ret_list <- c(ret_list, b = "b doesn't exist")
 }

  ret_list
}
```

Output

```
ret <- func()
ret
#$a
#[1] 1
#
#$b
#[1] "b doesn't exist"
```

**Edit**ed the above code to include `inherits = FALSE` in the `exists` function. If not `exists("c")` would return TRUE even when there isn't an object "c" as it would think "c" refer to the (base R) function `c()`.